# When the subsurf modifier is added to my weighted model, the weights break and deform the model. Can this be fixed or will I have to restart?

Tags: modifiers, armature, weight-painting

[image]

The model with both the subdivision surface before and after the armature.

Comment: Is the armature in its relaxed pose, or elsewise?

Comment: Sorry, but where do the weights break? And what is the problem?